# ngnix 301 redirect all urls to non lang prefix version

Tags: nginx

I want to 301 redirect

https://www.example.com/th/test123

to this

https://www.example.com/test123

See above url "th" is removed from url

So I want to redirect all website users to without lang prefix version of url.

Here is my config file

```
   server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    absolute_redirect off;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @prerender;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # force routes to index.html
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;

    location @prerender {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token JEWpuxaXuzdqvd7tKD1l;

        set $prerender 0;
        if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }
        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            # rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            # Following domain need to be dynamic
            rewrite .* /https://www.drivemate.asia$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }
        if ($prerender = 0) {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; # force routes to index.html
            rewrite .* /index.html break;
        }
    }
```

I am using prerender for server side rendering purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have locales list like `th`, `en`, `de` add this rewrite rule to the `server` context (for example, before the first `location` block):

```
rewrite ^/(?:th|en|de)(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 permanent;
```

Modify `(?:th|en|de)` capture group according to your list of used locales.